# Sql query for search not returning any reults

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql table and in that around 5000 rows are there . I have written a php code for searching the primary key and displaying the result using WHERE-IN clause. When I am searching only one primary key it is giving me desired result, but if I am searching for more than one primary key , it is not giving any result. Attaching my code with this . I am a beginner in this field . Any one can help me out ..??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Demo project">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">

</head>
    <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "site_info";
        $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        mysql_select_db("site_info");

        $siteid= $_GET['search1'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM total_database WHERE  primary_key IN ('$siteid')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$result){die(mysql_error());}


    ?>
    <body>
    <div class="container">



<table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
        <th>column 1</th>
        <th>column 2</th>
        <th>column 3</th>
        <th>column 4</th>
        <th>column 5</th>

        </tr>
        <?php


        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<form action=info.php method=GET>";
                echo"<tr>";
                echo "<td>" .$row["column1"]. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row["column2"]. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row["column3"]. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row["column4"]. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row["column5"]. "</td>";

              echo "<input type=hidden name=site_id value=".$row["primary_key"]."></input>";
                echo "<td>" ."<input class=btn type=submit value=select". "></td>";

                echo"</tr>";
                echo "</form>";


            }
        }

        ?> 


    </table>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: WARNING! Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Have you checked `$siteid` value?

Comment: Yea, I have echoed it and checked . Its showing correct values.

Comment: What values it is showing?

Comment: Its showing the primary key values which I have searched in the search boxand those values I have given is  seperated by coma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said your `$siteid` value is showing correct.
Suppose  `$siteid = '1,5,6'`

Now look at your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM total_database WHERE  primary_key IN ('$siteid')";
                                                            ^ here
```

After you pass `$siteid` to query what will you get?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM total_database WHERE  primary_key IN ('1,5,6')";
                                                            ^ here
```

So your looking for a `primary_key` with value `'1,5,6'`. Are you sure that you have such primary key?

What you need to do is to explode `$siteid` by a comma. And then implode values to a new string, so your query should look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM total_database WHERE  primary_key IN ('1','5','6')";
                                                            ^ here
```

Comment: Thanks , I understood what I have done wrong . Is there any other way so that I can get all the rows which I have searched in the search box..??

Comment: What do you mean - other way?

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
$siteid= $_GET['search1'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM total_database WHERE  primary_key IN ('$siteid')";
```

to something like this

```
$siteid= $_GET['search1'];
// if there is a , then re-format it instead of '1,2,3' to be '1','2','3'
if (strpos(",", $siteid) > -1){
    $t = explode(",", $siteid);
    $siteid = implode("','", $t);
}
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM total_database WHERE  primary_key IN ('$siteid')";
```